# Find/SED keeps ignoring some hidden files

Tags: linux, sed, find

Is there a way to ensure find/sed include hidden files during processing?

Comment: Can you give an example of what it's not finding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `find` nor `sed` care about hidden files; if hidden files are being ignored then its because your shell is ignoring them. On bash, set the `dotglob` option (via `shopt -s dotglob`) in order to cause globbing to match files that start with a `.`.

Comment: I don't agree.  `find` enumerates files all on its own, recursively; it does not rely on the shell command-line processing (and indeed often works better when command-line arguments are escaped or quoted to avoid shell processing).

Answer (score 2):

From the `find` manpage:

`-name pattern`

> Base  of  file  name  (the  path  with  the  leading directories
>        removed) matches shell  pattern  pattern.   **The metacharacters
>        ('*',  '?',  and '[]') match a '.' at the start of the base name
>        (this is a change in findutils-4.2.2**; see section STANDARDS CONFORMANCE    below).  To ignore a directory and the files under it,
>        use -prune; see an example in  the  description of `-wholename`.
>        Braces  are  not recognised  as being special, despite the fact
>        that some shells including Bash  imbue  braces  with  a  special
>        meaning  in  shell patterns.  The filename matching is performed
>        with the use of the fnmatch(3) library function.  Don't  forget
>        to  enclose  the pattern  in quotes in order to protect it from
>        expansion by the shell.

So check what version of `find` you are using, and consider upgrading.